# Why is this potentially helpful answer to some askers in the audit queue as a low-quality post?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

As a reviewer, it's just these "low quality post" audits that I sometimes do not pass. Here's a really puzzling one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9220804

In this case, the asker says "I cannot ping it, but I can access the the virtual machine." Someone answered:

> It looks like your firewall may be blocking ICMP requests. Depending on the security suite running on your server it'll take a different process to re-enable them.

I can definitely see this "gotcha" affecting multiple Azure users that *may* have a firewall in place causing this issue. It may have not been the correct answer in the case of this user, but I would hardly classify it like this:

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.

So I clicked that no, it's not a low quality post, and failed the audit.

What am I missing here? Is this truly considered a "low quality" post? There was a comment left that "it isn't an answer," but it clearly is:

Q: "Why can't I ping this virtual machine"
A: "Because ICMP is blocked."

Comment: I wouldn't call it "kinda a comment," but maybe that's not a universal opinion. Copying the text of the answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer as it now stands is so-so, not really VLQ, but [the revision history gives a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31992446/revisions) as to what's going on:

[image: Revision history entry with company tagline removed]

A company's tagline removed, and the post deleted by a moderator. It's quite likely that this post was one of several in which the user was trying to advertise a company or product.

The post, having been deleted in response to VLQ (or maybe spam) flags, is now a audit candidate.

Comment: I see! That definitely explains it. It's too bad I'd get bit in an audit because of something that was only _historically_ very low quality, but that's probably a _really_ hard problem to solve.

Comment: There's probably a proposal that addresses this problem; I'm trying to find it.

Comment: You're right, it did have a spam flag on it, a flag that was marked as helpful when the post was deleted. That triggered its use as an audit. I've cleared the spam flag and left the post deleted, which should remove it as an audit case. Normally, we don't edit these to remove the spammy content, but I think this happened in the middle of a series of edits to remove taglines.

Comment: @BradLarson Perhaps a solution could be that the *version* of the question is flagged an audit, rather than the question. In this case, the reviewers see exactly what the question was when it was flagged and marked as a helpful flag.

Comment: @Rob Submit a feature request?